# Filter elements by multiple tags with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm building a project submission platform and I'm creating a dynamic list of tags that you can filter projects by. At the moment, clicking on a tag correctly filters the projects but clicking on multiple tags overrides the previous ones.

I'd like the script to...

- Filter the projects by multiple projects
- Be more precise in how it filters - I'm using `:contains` right now but that means that filtering by 'design' also shows 'motion design' projects, which I don't want it to do
- When a tag is clicked again, remove that filter but keep other filters (e.g. user clicks 'animation' and 'motion design', then clicks 'animation' again to remove that filter, but the projects remain filtered by 'motion design')
- If no tags are active, show all projects (I have this working already)

I have it mostly working, it's just the last bits that have stumped me!

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  var projects = $('.msl-idea');
  var tags = $('#tags li')

  // Filter projects based on tags

  tags.on('click keypress', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    var value = $(this).text();

    if ($('#tags li.active').length === 0) {
      projects.show();
    } else {
      projects.hide();
      $(".msl-idea:contains(" + value + ")").show();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
#tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#tags li {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin: 0.25rem 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.75rem 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  font-family: 'HK Grotesk Bold';
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tags li.active {
  background: #f6c900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tags">
  <li>animation</li>
  <li>motion design</li>
  <li>photography</li>
  <li>videography</li>
  <li>design</li>
</ul>

<ul class="msl-idea-list">
  <li class="msl-idea">
    Some other content
    <ul class="msl-idea-tags">
      <li>animation</li>
      <li>motion design</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="msl-idea">
    Some other content
    <ul class="msl-idea-tags">
      <li>animation</li>
      <li>design</li>
      <li>photography</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="msl-idea">
    Some other content
    <ul class="msl-idea-tags">
      <li>photography</li>
      <li>videography</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so I finally got there using part of Carsten's answer and another nested `.each` function.

```
var tags = $('#tags li');
var projects = $('.msl-idea');

tags.on('click keypress', function() {
    
    projects.hide();

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    var activeTags = $("#tags li.active").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    
    projects.hide();

    $(activeTags).each(function () {
        $(".msl-idea:contains(" + this + ")").show();
    });
    
    if ( activeTags.length === 0 ) {
        projects.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  var projects = $('.msl-idea');
  var tags = $('#tags li')

  // Filter projects based on tags

  tags.on('click keypress', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var tags = $("#tags li.active").map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    if ($('#tags li.active').length === 0) {
      projects.show();
    } else {
      projects.show();
      $.each(tags,function(i,x) {
        $(".msl-idea:not(:contains(" + x + "))").hide();
      });
    }
  });
```

**Demo**

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  var projects = $('.msl-idea');
  var tags = $('#tags li')

  // Filter projects based on tags

  tags.on('click keypress', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var tags = $("#tags li.active").map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    if ($('#tags li.active').length === 0) {
      projects.show();
    } else {
      projects.show();
      $.each(tags,function(i,x) {
        $(".msl-idea:not(:contains(" + x + "))").hide();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#tags li {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin: 0.25rem 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.75rem 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  font-family: 'HK Grotesk Bold';
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tags li.active {
  background: #f6c900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tags">
  <li>animation</li>
  <li>motion design</li>
  <li>photography</li>
  <li>videography</li>
  <li>design</li>
</ul>

<ul class="msl-idea-list">
  <li class="msl-idea">
    Some other content
    <ul class="msl-idea-tags">
      <li>animation</li>
      <li>motion design</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="msl-idea">
    Some other content
    <ul class="msl-idea-tags">
      <li>animation</li>
      <li>design</li>
      <li>photography</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="msl-idea">
    Some other content
    <ul class="msl-idea-tags">
      <li>photography</li>
      <li>videography</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I'm after, which I think is my fault - I don't think I explained myself clearly enough in my question. How would I change this so that when clicking multiple tags, it expands the filters rather than limiting them? For example, with this code if I select 'animation' and 'motion design' it looks for projects that contains both of these. How would I change it to look for projects that contain either of them?

Comment: @ElliotParker So if multiple tags is selected then it shall only return those that contains all tags selected?

Comment: No, it should show projects that contain any of the multiple tags selected. So if I'm looking for projects about design, photography, videography or animation, I can select those tags and it will show any project that contains one of those tags. Does that make sense?